# How to get React to update after first API call

Tags: reactjs

I made the first API call successfully and got the data and rendered it.

What I want to do:

- I update the rendered data according to the button click.
- That means that I get the  value of the clicked button then I call the function getCategory, after calling the function I update the state
- I assume that after I update the state of Category, the call should get updated, that doesn't happen.

The state gets updated (I printed it in console) but the component doesn't make new call after receiving it.

Full code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hgg1se?file=index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      news: [],
      category: ''
    }

    this.getCategory = this.getCategory.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=`+this.state.category+`&apiKey=2179f689f9224a2993696143ec3e97eb`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.articles)
        this.setState({
          news: response.articles
        })

      })
  }
  /* this function gets called after button clicked to update the state */
  getCategory(event) {
    this.setState({ category: event.target.value }, function(){ console.log(this.state.category) } );
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>

        <div className='container'>
          <form>
            <div className="form-group">
              <div className='col-sm-12'>
                <input type="text" className="form-control text-primary" placeholder="search" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          /* here where I get the value of clicked button */
          <button type="button" onClick={this.getCategory} value="Technology" class="btn btn-primary"> Technology </button>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.getCategory} value="Business" class="btn btn-primary"> Business </button>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.getCategory} value="Science" class="btn btn-primary"> Science </button>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.getCategory} value="Entertainment" class="btn btn-primary"> Entertainment </button>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.getCategory} value="Health" class="btn btn-primary"> Health </button>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.getCategory} value="Sports" class="btn btn-primary"> Sports </button>

        </div>

        <div className='container'>
          <ul className="list-group">

            {this.state.news.map((article) =>
              <li className='list-group-item border-left-0 border-right-0'>
                <div className="row">



                  <div className='col-9'>
                    <a href={article.url}>
                      {article.title}
                    </a>
                  </div>


                  <div className="col-3">
                    <a href={article.url} className="thumbnail">
                      <img src={article.urlToImage != 'null' ? article.urlToImage : 'http://www.publicengagement.ac.uk/sites/default/files/styles/content_width/public/hero/large-crowd-of-people-small.jpg'} class="img-fluid" />
                    </a>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </li>
            )}

          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: What do you mean "after I update the state of Category, the call should get updated"? The only API call is in `componentDidMount()`, which is only ever executed once, when the component initially mounts.

Comment: This is what you want. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-f3dnkt?file=index.js

Comment: @HardikModha Thank you, could you please add an answer so I accept it?

Comment: You can accept @seunggabi's answer. :)

Comment: @HardikModha I did :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't understand react component lifecycle.

Read this page. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle

```
// [Mount]: just Once called. similar constructor.
// constructor -> componentWillMount -> getDerivedStateFromProps -> render -> componentDidMount

// [Update]: calling after mount
// getDerivedStateFromProps -> shouldComponentUpdate -> getDerivedStateFromProps -> getSnapshotBeforeUpdate -> componentDidUpdate
```

therefore you have to change `componentDidMount` -> `componentDidUpdate`.

Reactjs Component lifecycle flow Update after Mount.

Comment: Thank you for your response, actually I am learning and working on improving my knowledge with react, I will be reviewing lifecycle methods

Comment: @tarekhassan Okay I grad to help to you. I also study reactjs. Good Luck~

Comment: Moving the code as is to `componentDidUpdate` will lead to an infinite update loop (the page makes a new Ajax request as soon as the previous one has resolved.)